# Point size based on attribute value in QGIS

Tags: qgis

First time user with QGIS. Basically using the MMQGIS plugin I've geocoded a number of points to a map of Ireland. These points reference a club which received a grant. However, I want to be able to distinguish which club received a larger grant.

Is it possible to do this, e.g. various points weighted by grant? So a club which received larger grants have larger points?

Comment: This [tutorial](http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/02/styling-vector-data-in-qgis-using-size.html) (although a few years old but still applies) is quite useful in showing how to change the properties (colour, size) of points based on attributes (or in your case, grants).

Comment: Most welcome buddy! There are quite a few questions asked here in GIS:SE which you could do a search on to learn more about how to do some pretty cool stuff :)

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who is coming to this question and finds the links provided dead, you can achieve this by going into layer properties -> Symbology -> change to Graduated from the first dropdown and then change 'Method' to 'Size'.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to change the size AND color of my point symbols based on a field value so I wanted to use Categorized symbology, not Graduated. The following worked for me:

Layer Properties -> Symbology -> Categorized then click on the dropdown arrow to the far right of Symbol. Click "Configure Symbol" in the pop-up window. In the "Symbol Settings" window make sure Marker is highlighted (it should be, by default). Then go to the "Data Defined Override" to the far right of Size. Hover over "Field Type" then select the field you want to use to scale the size from the options on the left.

If field values used for scaling need to be multiplied by a factor to make them "pretty": Go back into the "Data Defined Override" and click on the Edit... option. This will open Expression String Builder where you can add a multiplication factor.

[image: My end result map]

Comment: I think that categorized styling is meant for categoric data, hence you get that awfully long legend: since it will pick every single value in the dataset as a new category. **Rule**-based styling is probably more appropriate.

Comment: "Data Defined Override" is inactive.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question. So far I have found this: http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/02/styling-vector-data-in-qgis-using-size.html.
It's an old version of QGIS, but should work the same!

Comment: The link is no longer working, unfortunately.